# Failure to send more than 9 emails through Mandril & Parse-Cloud-Code

Tags: javascript, email, parse-platform, mandrill, parse-cloud-code

I've been having a problem with sending email templates with mandrill. The set up that I have right now is javascript on a parse server which is setup with a background job to send emails once a day to each of the users using mandrill's api.
I came across an issue when sending large amount of emails, for some reason I can’t get mandrill to send any more than 9 email templates at a time, with over 400 needing to be sent. This shouldn't be a problem for I've been sending emails through this account for some time and have good reputation.
I tried putting a delay in the email, and changing options in the sending of templates, such as making them send async. But to no avail only 9 at maximum are to be sent.

```
exports.FunctionSentDripEmailTemplateFour = function (user,TempateNum,isLastEmail,status,testing){
    var mandrillKey = 'my-key';
    var Mandrill = require('mandrill');

    if(testing){ // send the email to me if testing
        EmailParams.message.to[0].email = 'test@email.com'; 
        EmailParams.message.merge_vars[0].rcpt = 'test@email.com';
    }else{
        EmailParams.message.to[0].email = user.get('email'); 
        EmailParams.message.merge_vars[0].rcpt = user.get('email');
    }

    EmailParams.message.subject="Subject";
    EmailParams.template_name = "Template name";
    EmailParams.template_content[0].name = "Template content name";

    //console.log("T: " + TempateNum + " M: " + EmailParams.message.to[0].email);
    Mandrill.initialize(mandrillKey);
    Mandrill.sendTemplate(EmailParams, function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    if(isLastEmail == true){
        //(finishes the parse job function)
        if(testing){
            status.success("Test Email Job completed successfully.");
        }else{
            status.success("Email Job completed successfully.");
        }
    }
    return new Parse.Promise(); 
}
```

Also, I only want these emails to be sent personally, I don't want to use carbon copies for I am using this elsewhere with making changes to each and every email.
Do you have any ideas? It would mean a lot to me.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am calling Mailgun API from Parse Cloud Code. Did you figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is performing an asynchronous network request (Mandrill.sendTemplate()) but it is immediately returning without waiting for this call to complete.

It looks like you're halfway there towards making this function perform as expected. You should initialize the Parse.Promise first, and return that promise object at the end of the function. This promise, in turn, should be resolved when the Mandrill code finishes.

```
exports.FunctionSentDripEmailTemplateFour = function (user,TempateNum,isLastEmail,status,testing){
var mandrillKey = 'my-key';
var Mandrill = require('mandrill');

if(testing){ // send the email to me if testing
    EmailParams.message.to[0].email = 'test@email.com'; 
    EmailParams.message.merge_vars[0].rcpt = 'test@email.com';
}else{
    EmailParams.message.to[0].email = user.get('email'); 
    EmailParams.message.merge_vars[0].rcpt = user.get('email');
}

EmailParams.message.subject="Subject";
EmailParams.template_name = "Template name";
EmailParams.template_content[0].name = "Template content name";

var promise = new Parse.Promise()
//console.log("T: " + TempateNum + " M: " + EmailParams.message.to[0].email);
Mandrill.initialize(mandrillKey);
Mandrill.sendTemplate(EmailParams, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    promise.resolve(res);
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    promise.reject(err);
});

// commented out isLastEmail block - I am not sure this is the right place for that functionality

return promise; 
}
```

You will now be able to do the following:

```
FunctionSentDripEmailTemplateFour(user,templateNum,isLastEmail,status,testing).then(function(result) {
    status.success("One email sent successfully");
}, function(err) {
    status.error("Failed to send email");
});
```

Rewriting this code to send more than one email is left as an exercise to the reader. You should be able to follow Parse's Promises guide to rewrite this into a set of parallel promises.